# Why my left drag/slider is working but the right drag/slider not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js

This is my `jsfiddle`  https://jsfiddle.net/dibyendu/sgj23fg9/  .
I am not sure what I am missing here that my `right slider` is working but not the `left slider`.Also how I can make it like they should not `overlap` or `cross` each other while `sliding`

Comment: Hmm, looks to be the other way around to me. Your left slider is working and your right slider just jumps out from underneath your mouse and attaches to the left wall when clicked.

Comment: :) yeh I mean to say not sliding left wise but sliding perfect right wise

Comment: Well, something that strikes me right away is that you're assigning the same id of "active" to two rects. That will cause some inconsistencies. I changed it in your fiddle and reran, though, and it didn't fix it. Maybe you'd want to test the left side and then when you can guarantee that the left side works, test the right side in a separate fiddle. When both work separately, then incorporate the javascript into one file and test.

Comment: Ok I will do that right now

Comment: your changing variables in one case then using the changed variables in the next. You need to have a good tidy of your code make sure the two functions arent conflicting

Comment: Here is the fiddle both left and right is working https://jsfiddle.net/dibyendu/gsxfnwou/

Comment: thats not what your original was about. You had two separate rectangles

Comment: This is the original ,  I have crated two rectangles for my requirement. You can see here actually both left and right slider is working

Comment: Just now I checked problem is here I think `function ldragresize` I am getting `NaN` here `d.x2 = Math.max(0, Math.min(d.x2 + width - (dragbarw / 2), d3.event.x)); 
   alert(d.x2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed it here https://jsfiddle.net/dibyendu/erg8jypp/  . The each `rect` should be inside separate `<g>`